# Count of number of layers in the hierarchy

Tags: sql

I have to write a SQL query to count number of layers that are in a hierarchy.

As I am new to this, I am not sure how to do that.
I have a table that has data like

```
Manager Id.   Person Id
```

And manager hierarchy is like

```
A reports to B 
And B has direct reports C,D
```

So if we are checking manager A then we should get output 3 as this hierarchy has 3 layers
I tried this SQL query but it is not returning the desired data

```
   SELECT employee_id, last_name, manager_id, LEVEL
   FROM employees
   CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;
```

Comment: So, You are using `Oracle` ?

Comment: please specify DB you use. Code you provided is specific to Oracle

Answer (score 0):

[As per syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332); If you are checking Manager A then you should specify start (root) node of hierarchy using `START WITH`.

The following query shall give you required result.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LEVEL) AS hierarchy_layers
FROM employees
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR employee_id = manager_id
START WITH manager_id = 'A';
```

Output :

```
hierarchy_layers
3
```